# DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, datatable

I used Datatables in laravel and getting below warning message:

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more
>   information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

I can't get the JSON data from my table in database

here my controller

```
 public function data()
    {
       // return Datatables::of(Employee::select("*"))->make(true);
        $users = Employee::select(['id','employee_name','gender', 'join_date', 'identity_no', 'birthdate', 'idaddress']);
        return Datatables::of($users)->make();
    }
```

Route

```
Route::any("data", "EmployeeController@data");
```

Model

```
 public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            "id" => "id",
            "nik" => "Nik",
            "employee_name" => "Nama Pegawai",
            "gender" => "Jenis kelamin",
            "join_date" => "Tgl bergabung",
            "identity_no" => "No identitas",
            "birthdate" => "Tgl Lahir",
            "idaddress" => "Alamat",
        ];
    }
```

Table

```
<table class="table table-bordered" datatable="{{ url("hr/employee/data") }}">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th dt-field="id"> {{ $model->label("id") }} </th>
        <th dt-field="nik"> {{ $model->label("nik") }} </th>
        <th dt-field="employee_name"> {{ $model->label("employee_name") }} </th>
        <th dt-field="gender"> {{ $model->label("gender") }} </th>
        <th dt-field="join_date"> {{ $model->label("join_date") }} </th>
        <th dt-field="identity_no"> {{ $model->label("identity_no") }} </th>
        <th dt-field="birthdate"> {{ $model->label("birthdate") }} </th>
        <th dt-field="idaddress"> {{ $model->label("idaddress") }} </th>
        <th dt-col="#dt-action" sort="false" search="false"> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
```

Where am I doing wrong ? How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to select the nik in your select query. If that will be done, it should work. When there is any field missing in datatables, it throws this error.

Comment: even I used eloquent still get error `return Datatables::of(Employee::select("*"))->make(true);`

Comment: Just add nik field as well in below line of code.
        $users = Employee::select(['id','employee_name','gender', 'join_date', 'identity_no', 'birthdate', 'idaddress']);